# Spaces in url query not getting decoded in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following URL query -

```
http://localhost:8000/api/passenger-census/?public_location_description==SW%206th%20&%20Salmon
```

however, the spaces are not being decoded and the resulting query that django parses is

```
GET /api/passenger-census/?public_location_description=SW%206th%20&%20Salmon
```

which returns a `null` since the string to be found is "SW 6th & Salmon".

Django code

`views.py` -

```
class PassengerCensusViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = PassengerCensus.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PassengerCensusSerializer
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter,DjangoFilterBackend,OrderingFilter,)
    search_fields = ('route_number', 'direction','service_key','stop_seq',
                     'location_id','public_location_description',)
    filter_fields = ('summary_begin_date','route_number','direction','service_key','stop_seq','location_id',
                    'public_location_description','ons','offs','x_coord','y_coord','geom_2913','geom_4326',)
    ordering_fields = '__all__'
```

---

`serializer.py`

```
class PassengerCensusSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PassengerCensus
        fields = '__all__'
```

---

What is the issue here?

Comment: How sure are you that the problem isn't the unescaped ampersand?

Comment: You have encoded your parameter wrong. Querystring parameters (as opposed to path elements) should be encoded by replacing spaces by `+`, not `%20`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The spaces aren't the issue, your ampersand is the problem.
Ampersand is the separator between the different parameters, which are name=value pairs.

Parsing your query string results in:

A name of `public_location_description` with a value of `=SW%206th%20`
and
`%20Salmon` with no value.

Escape your ampersand by replacing it with `%26` (and remove the redundant '=') to get a url of:

http://localhost:8000/api/passenger-census/?public_location_description=SW%206th%20%26%20Salmon

and try it again

Comment: how do I have Django escape an ampersand automatically when a user enters a '&' in a query parameter?

Comment: URLs are not made for human input.  That's what HTML forms are for.